# Angular2 RC1 zonejs imports and proxy design

Tags: javascript, proxy

I have a project that was in an older version of Angular and that I am now trying to update to RC.1.

In my old version, Angular2 files such as angular2/http or so were loaded in the `index.html` using a `<script>` tag. Now in RC1 they are loaded through zonejs.

Zonejs makes requests such as `@angular/core` and I have to find a way for my proxy to redirect those kinds of requests into the node_modules folder.

On my proxy I have 2 functions, one parsing the URL and one making requests and acting as an "proxy".

```
var ParseUrl = function(Url : string) {
var api_name = (Url).substring(1,Url.slice(1).indexOf('/')+1);
console.log("DEBUG: " + Url);
if (api_name === 'dynamic-components' || api_name === 'framework' || api_name === 'node_modules')
    return {
                "api_name" : "",
                 "api_endpoint" : "",
                 "url" : host + ':' + port + Url + '.js' };
    if (api_name === '@angular')
        return {
                "api_name" : "",
                 "api_endpoint" : "",
                 "url" : host + ':' + port + '/node_modules/' + Url + '/index.js' };
    if(api_name === 'framework' || api_name === 'public')
        return undefined;
    var api_endpoint = GetAPIEndPoint(api_name);
    console.log("DEBUG: " + api_endpoint);
    if (api_endpoint == -1)
        return null;
    var url = (Url).slice(api_name.length+1);
    console.log("DEBUG: " + url);
    return { "api_name" : api_name,
             "api_endpoint" : api_endpoint,
             "url" : url };
}


app.use('/public', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/framework', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'framework')));
app.use('/dynamic-components', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dynamic-components')));
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '/../node_modules')));
app.use('/@angular', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,'/../node_modules/@angular')));

app.get('/*/*', function (req, res, next) {
    var parsedUrl = ParseUrl(req.originalUrl);
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (parsedUrl === undefined) {
            console.log('undef');
            return;
        }
        if (parsedUrl === null) {
            next();
            return;
        }
        request(parsedUrl.api_endpoint + parsedUrl.url).pipe(res);
}, 30);
});
```

I'm not sure how to redirect the `@angular` calls. The way I have it now will break since it always enters the ParseUrl function and by adding index.js at every @angular call it eventually gets in an infinite loop. How should I allow clients access to the @angular folder properly?